# Change of Connection impact on Code

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, oracle, c#-4.0

I am using asp.net and currently working with SQL SERVER 2008.
In my code all the DML operation is happening with the help of SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter.

But when If my database move to **ORACLE** or **MySQL** then I would need to write the code for  ORACLE  -- OLEDBConnection, OLEDBCommand, OLEDBDataAdapter
MySQL   -- Would need to include a  MySQL dll.

Now due to this huge change I would need to write the entire code again.

1. Is there any way to overcome this problem that we write the code at once and that would not depend on the database provider?
2. Does the Entity Framework come in this picture anywhere?

Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, EF comes into point 1.

Comment: EF would help, but this was an issue even before the days of EF. What you would do is wrap DB logic in a data access layer, and only code on the DAL would depend on the DB provider.

Answer (score 2):

If you write your data access layer using the base classes [`DbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx), [`DbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) and the other classes in [`System.Data.Common`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tahwysy.aspx), you can pass in and use *any* of the inheriting types.

This means that you write your data access layer once but *inject* the actual types you do use, possibly using an [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container.

Most ORMs, including EF, use this technique to be database agnostic.

Comment: Just to add, using the Interfaces to these like IDbConnection or IDbCommand will give more flexibility